# Access top 10 by price using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
select top 10 Account_Name, Indemnity_Paid/Claim_Count as Indemnity_Cost
from Final_For_DB
Group by Account_Name
order by Indemnity_Cost desc;
```

I have three columns in my FINALFOR_DB, which are:

account_name

indemnity_paid

claim_count

I want to write a query that will give me the top 10 values that are grouped by `account_name`. Indemnity cost is calculated by dividing `indemnity_paid` by `claim_count`  to get the exact cost.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit:**

Now I have this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 [FINAL_FOR_DB].[Indemnity_Paid]/[FINAL_FOR_DB].[Claim_Count] AS Indemnity_Cost, final_for_db.Claimant_Name, final_for_db.Account_Name, final_for_db.Claim_ID, final_for_db.File_Date, final_for_db.Resolution_Date, final_for_db.Claim_Status, final_for_db.State_Filed, final_for_db.Expense_Amount
    FROM final_for_db
    GROUP BY [FINAL_FOR_DB].[Indemnity_Paid]/[FINAL_FOR_DB].[Claim_Count], final_for_db.Claimant_Name, final_for_db.Account_Name, final_for_db.Claim_ID, final_for_db.File_Date, final_for_db.Resolution_Date, final_for_db.Claim_Status, final_for_db.State_Filed, final_for_db.Expense_Amount
    HAVING (((final_for_db.Account_Name)="Exxon"))
    ORDER BY [FINAL_FOR_DB].[Indemnity_Paid]/[FINAL_FOR_DB].[Claim_Count] DESC;
```

I would like to know if it's possible to have top 10 claims for each account in one query. In this one I had to use a condition that had Exxon as Account name.

Comment: Are you using pass through query? above SQL code would not work in access  as Access requires aggregation function for all involved fields..

Comment: and another question, if you are grouping by account_name why aren't you summing up the claims_count? if claim_count is already a calculated field, why are you grouping by account_name?

Comment: @krish this one works in Access///

Comment: Have missed your edits :)

Comment: Is there any way to include all accounts in one query?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explicitly state it, but I assume the above query did not do what you wanted.

This would probably be because calculations from the `select` cannot be reused in clauses such as `order by`, `where`, etc.

You would need to explicitly perform the calculation again in those subsequent clauses, wherever it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its faster in terms of performance(tbh never tested): I would use:

```
select T1.* from 
(Select Top 10 Account_Name, Indemnity_Paid/Claim_Count as Indemnity_Cost
From Final_For_DB
WHERE account_name = "account_name"
) AS T1
Order By T1.Indemnity_Cost DESC;
```

ALSO: Access SQL requires aggregation function for all fields involved in a Group function. I would write your SQL something like this:

```
select T1.* from 
(Select Top 10 Account_Name, sum(Indemnity_Paid)/sum(Claim_Count) as Indemnity_Cost
From Final_For_DB
WHERE account_name = "condition" 
Group By Account_Name) AS T1
Order By T1.Indemnity_Cost DESC;
```

Since you are groping by account_name you should also sum the "indemnity_paid" & claim_count field across all matched rows unless that field are already a calculated field in your table/query. in that case you can simply use the first method but also sort by account_name

Comment: can I have more than one account name?

Comment: Remove the where condition @krnactry

Comment: it would give the maximum cost for each company. I need top 10 claims in terms of magnitude of indemnity cost per person (this is calculated by dividing indemnity paid by claim count)